# Can Python make an OS similar to Windows?

Tags: python, operating-system

I want to make a OS that could be gaming-friendly (like Windows) yet easy to use. I can already use Python perfectly fine, and I'm looking to see if I could make an OS with it. Is it possible? If not, what are some Python-like coding languages that I could use?

I've looked in to Buildroot but it uses the Makefile language which I am extremely confused about, it's just non-logical (at least to me).

I expect it to be possible because C# is ***quite*** the complex language and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Neutrino You in theory can, it's not an easy task you would first have to make the python bytecode interpreter sit directly on bare metal this still involves quite a bit of C. At that point you would have a micro-kernel with the rest of the operating system written in Python. People have prototyped this in years past. I believe project cleese is the closest you will get to something that you're looking for.

Project Cleese
https://github.com/jtauber/cleese

Comment: Thank you, Dave. Well I guess I'll have to learn some C. :/

Answer (score 1):

Never use python to build any sort of OS, especially if you want it to be gaming-friendly. Python is a very slow language.

To build an OS, you should use a language from the C family

Comment: Really? I always thought that Python was a fast enough language that it could be at least possible to build an OS, well I guess not. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: building an OS is perhaps the most performance-necessary task there is. You can’t even use c++ in some cases because c is faster

Comment: @Neutrino maybe considering building some starter projects at this stage. Building an operating system requires a significant amount of work, dedication, commitment and knowledge. If you don't know assembly or how interrupts work or what this means `mov ax, 0x10` (If you are on x86), maybe step back a bit and build some simpler projects. Some suggestions may be learning C or C# etc (Not Python) and then building a low-level system like implementing a standard library to understand how it works under the hood. Or, consider writing a compiler of some sort and get familiar with executable formats

Comment: When writing an operating system, just know that nothing is setup for you. Don't expect just to `import os` to get features working. You'll need to implement that yourself (Renderer, standard library, memory management, drivers etc)